# SQL connection string in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection-string

I read different way of writing of connection string in article

> http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Can you please explain me where to use `Server` and where to use `Data Source` ? Similarly where to use `Database` and where to use `Initial Catalog`. Please explain in detail. I am new in SQL Server.

Comment: can't you try few combinations of those parameters and verify if works or not? what did you try and has failed/worked so far?

Comment: I think this experiment will give him false understanding and may be he continue to think that as correct forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those connection string keywords can be used interchangeably. When ADO.Net is parsing the connection string, it will create a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class (in case of Sql Server) and map the keywords withing the connection string to the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` properties.

For example, "data Source", "server", "address", "addr", and "network address" all map to the `DataSource` property -- you can use either one of those to specify the data source.  Similarly, "Initial Catalog" and "database" map to the `InitialCatalog` property.

Take a look at the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dce36088%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and its properties on MSDN where you can find more information on their keyword mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a valid ADO.NET connection string using different keywords.
There are a lot of aliases, for example: "Data Source" and "Server" means both the same thing.
The same for "Database" and "Initial Catalog".

You can find a list of valid keywords and their aliases here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx